# c static analysis calculate load and store instructions

Tags: c

May be anybody know about this.

I try to evaluate application requirements without any hardware. Code of application is some big. I try to measure for this simple count of instructions and count of data dependent of this instructions.
Data - its operations of load and store to memory.

I want to know all load and store of double variable in my code.

Ideally if I get count load and store from some of function (targeted or marked by me) to second function.

I think it may be done by some of static analysis of object file.

Get me right target please.
Thanks for your time

Comment: You cant for the virtual hardware. Choose the one and see what the compiler output is.

Comment: Yes of course if compiler generate code it code is architecture oriented, but if I measure load and store instructions on the running application it stand so difficult because some of load/store work with cash L1/L2/L3, some load is out-of-order executions and etc. Because I hope that static analysis can be more suited for me. How to get statistic by load store from compiler ? gcc or intel cc or something else

Comment: You can't consider it abstracting  from the actual hardware.  Voting to close as too broad

Comment: Apparently something like this can be implemented with the help of llvm

Comment: Leave all the compiler stages outputs, see what is there and write your program which will count the cash load/stores. No cheque or card, only the cash ones. BTW you just need to parse the output after the gcc phase xxxx (you need to check it yourself) https://godbolt.org/g/67NjYj